# Get a version ready to use from github

Tags: java, jquery, github, fullcalendar

I tried to figure out how I can build a final version of fullcalendar.js from github. On github, the src files is compound of multifiles and the final version is unique...

The indication on github is the following but I didn't catch what I have to do

> You must have a Java runtime environment (accessible by the java
>   command) for minification. Then, run make zip and check the dist/
>   directory for your newly created ZIP archive. To start fresh, run the
>   make clean command.

The github page is https://github.com/arshaw/fullcalendar. If anyone has an idea where to find a tutorial to explain how to minify for dummies I would be pleased....

I try to use the console Windows. Then to write java. Return, then write make zip Return  and then I get a error message...

Answer (score 0):

From the Github page it looks like the Makefile handles the minification for you. Just make sure you have a JRE installed and from the command line navigate to the repository directory and run make zip, and your zip should be in the dist/ folder.

Answer (score 0):

I had to use my vmplayer running centos 6 to run this command. Appearantly we are expected to know that we have to be on linux to do the compile. I too tried to do this on Windows 7 at first but ended up on linux.